# Fuse two separate objects

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects, vertices

First I really need to clarify, I’ve watched people use the boolean method, but I swear I’ve seen people just able to drag an object into another and it automatically fuses without any interior meshes or extra work. Problem is, I can’t remember what it’s called or how to do it. Was this not a recent addition to Blender? I may be wrong.

Say I have a sphere and a cone and I want to make something resembling an ice cream cone, but I want the hidden half of the sphere to be gone (so that it’s 1 object, a semi-sphere and a cone attached to one another with no hidden geometry).

I don’t want to count vertices or do any extra selection -> deletion/vertices manipulation work to get this effect. I just recall seeing people drag one object into another. Say, they drag the sphere down onto the flat surface of the cone and the sphere geometry that enters the interior of the cone just disappears and the vertices where the two objects touch hook onto each other automatically.

Am I confused or is this something possible? If it’s possible, I assume it’s some sort of modifier that gets attached to the cone? This will seriously speed up my work flow, so if anyone has any answers that would be wonderful! Thanks.

—-

Edit: All of the answers are helpful, thanks! I likely saw someone using the Bool Tool addon. Ctrl + J and Convex Hull and Bridging will also be very helpful. I really appreciate the quick responses.

Comment: It's possible they are using the booltool addon.  With it enabled you can multiselect and do Ctrl + Numpad +/- to do a quick union/difference, and I think Ctrl + Shift + etc does the same but *automatically applies the operation*

Answer (score 1):

Orient your meshes when they are still separate:

[image: Join1]

Join them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>:

[image: Join2]

Select the whole (joined) mesh in edit mode and select *mesh* > *Convex Hull*:

[image: Join3]

Resulting shape:

[image: Join4]